# Priority between seed and webseed in libtorrent

Tags: c++, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

everyone.
I've read this article http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual-ref.html but I can't find how can I set up priority between seed and webseed with using libtorrent. 
I will be very appreciated for your answers.

Comment: what do you mean by "priority". prioritize what?

Comment: I have a torrent file with tracker list and webseeds. As client I want to download files from seeds and ignore webseed. But I can't create torrent file without webseed.

Comment: if you simply want to pretend the webseeds don't exist, you can remove them from the torrent_info object before adding it to the session. It just occurs to me that there's no API to remove web seeds. is that what you're looking to do? (because there are ways to do it, they're just not very straight-forward)